# CSS or JS way for setting an absolute div height 100%

Tags: java, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I'm developing a small application with JSF and Bootstrap. The problem is that I can't set height 100% to an aside and absolute div.

I tried with CSS first, but I think its not possible to get it in that way so now I'm trying with JQuery without any success.

I'm using this JQuery function:

```
function resize_sidebar() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').height(h);
}

window.onresize = resize_sidebar();

resize_sidebar();
```

but it's not working as expected, because it doesn't fill the full height.

I hope you can give me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: Maybe my English is bad, but I can't understand your question. Could you explain a bit more about the problem? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I only want an absolute div with height 100%, without changing my current web behaviour. If you go into the url I posted you'll know exactly what I want.

Comment: @NoSense outerHeight is not applicable for $document or $window so I think is not valid for my purpose

Comment: @Pablo I went to the website you linked and it looks to me like the black bar is filling up the entire pages height. Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

Now I see the problem. My resolution is very big and the content is smaller than the sidebar and all is looking fine but when I resize my screen The content get bigger by the floating boxes but sidebar still have the height of the window.

That should do the trick:

```
function resize_sidebar() {
    var h = $('#wrap').height();
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').height(h);
}

resize_sidebar();

​$(window).on('resize', function(){
    resize_sidebar();
   ...do something else...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using pure css

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 250px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I know that bottom:0 should do the trick, but I tried it before without success, maybe because of the footer div or something.

Comment: @Pablo you might try position: fixed as well, In my opinion its best to use css whenever possible.

Comment: I cannot use position fixed because I want that div to scroll down so the only way is with absolute position. Obviously CSS is always better for layout design.